# Bloomberg Server API and Ruby/Python

Tags: python, ruby, bloomberg

Im looking to write a new application in ruby/python which uses a feed from bloomberg and am stuck trying to find any documentation for using (or even setting up) Bloomberg Server API with either of these languages.

Does anyone have any good links to tutorials for this or maybe some boilerplate code to get set up? Or is it best to just stick to the three main supported languages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you check out some questions at SO on this. It might help you

- [Bloomberg API request timing out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1443446/bloomberg-api-request-timing-out)
- [Asynchronous data through Bloomberg's new data API (COM v3) with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2005234/asynchronous-data-through-bloombergs-new-data-api-com-v3-with-python)

Resolver is an spreadsheet implementation in IronPython and has a very good integration for Bloomberg API

- http://www.resolversystems.com/documentation/apidocs/MarketData_Bloomberg.html

Answer (score 4):

The Bloomberg Open API (BLPAPI) v3.5 release now includes a native Python SDK.

http://www.openbloomberg.com/2012/11/21/open-api-blpapi-v3-5-x-released/

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple Client access API which I wrote with the help of the mentioned links as well as some others. Not everything is implemented but it is a good start.

https://github.com/bpsmith/pybbg

Comment: Care to write a summary here for the convenience of the readers here?