# Access Bloomberg API from python

Tags: python, bloomberg

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Bloomberg Server API and Ruby/Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4036009/bloomberg-server-api-and-ruby-python)

What's the best way to access Bloomberg server API from Python?
I need something that'll work on both Windows and Linux (the posts I've seen so far on SO are all for windows specific solutions). And I would prefer to use cpython and not jython etc.

Comment: those are windows specific solutions

Comment: AFAIK that's all there is; you'd likely need to interop via COM.

Answer (score 4):

The Bloomberg Open API (BLPAPI) v3.5 release now includes a native Python SDK.

[Bloomberg Server API and Ruby/Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4036009/bloomberg-server-api-and-ruby-python)

Answer (score 1):

It works with standard python(I am using it), but your problem is it won't work using the terminal api on linux as the bloomberg software is only available for windows.

If you must have access on linux, then you'll need a server api type license which will allow you to query the server without the client running on the terminal.  You need to speak with your sales rep to get pricing and more information about it.